# Trying to get an FFT to work on an fpga to get sound data

Tags: fft, fourier-transform, ifft

I am trying to get an FFT to work with Verilog to bin frequency data to be able to tell what note is being played.
I am using an FPGA BASYS3 with a pmodmic3 which samples at $20\,KHz$ and outputs 12-bit data.

I am using this FFT core generator to generate an FFT that I would like to use: https://zipcpu.com/dsp/2018/10/02/fft.html

Based on my understanding, I require 1024 bins to be able to distinguish notes at lower frequencies. However, after trying this out with my fpga, I'm having no success with getting data out.

Following the link, I generated an FFT with 1024 points, 12 input bits, 12 output bits, but am not able to get it to work. Can anyone point out something that I am doing wrong? I can post the code if needed.

Comment: I do suggest posting the code. However, FFT might not be the way to go if you're doing pitch detection (especially at lower frequencies...)

Comment: Also, can you please be more explicit about what you mean by *am not able to get it to work* ?  **What** doesn't work?  "The car is broken" doesn't help much in trying to diagnose the issue: does it need gas? does it need a new spark plug? does it need a new tire? does it need a new axel?

Comment: @PeterK. When the fft finishes a transform, CE line will be high, and this signals data ready, and then my always block would extract the output into a large vector which i then process to find the frequencies. But it seems like im waiting really long and CE line does not go high at all becaused i assigned it to an led to visualize

Comment: @Jdip i will post soon, what do you suggest for pitch detection without an fft?

Comment: Search this website for "pitch detection" :)
Also, [Pitch detection Review](http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~ich/classes/mumt611_05/Presentations.old/mumt614pitchtrack.pdf)